# What is the story of the Chimera?

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures, hittite, anatolia

The [Neo-Hittite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syro-Hittite_states) Chimera (850–750 BC) from [Karkemish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carchemish) is housed in the Museum of Anatolian Civilizations in Ankara, Turkey:

[image: Neo-Hitte Chimera]

<sub><sub>"[Museum of Anatolian Civilizations080](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Museum_of_Anatolian_Civilizations080.jpg#/media/File:Museum_of_Anatolian_Civilizations080.jpg)" by Georges Jansoone ([JoJan](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:JoJan)) - Self-photographed. Licensed under Public Domain via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).</sub></sub>

This chimera is presumably a precursor to the more well known [Greek chimera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_%28mythology%29). Do we know of any stories associated with it? Is it mentioned in Hittite mythology?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After researching on the topic for a considerable amount of time, it seems most of the sources which describe the Neo-Hittite Chimera, do not contain any myths about the creature nor any in-depth details.

Therefore, it leads me to believe what another source said (emphasis mine):

> "On the [orthostats](http://www.metmuseum.org/toah/works-of-art/43.135.2) at Neo-Hittite sites, **the Chimaera had no narrative context and served only to ward off evil**, but in Greek myth the beast was to be conquered by a hero"
>
> <sub><sub>source: http://cuartmuseum.colorado.edu/collection.bak/classics/greekvases/orientalizing.html</sub></sub>

Which means, the Neo-Hittite Chimera was created just to "ward off evil" and hence does not have any myths associated with it.